# Why is Grunt ignoring my file paths?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I have the entire bootstrap-sass project in a git submodule. Why is grunt looking at sass/bootstrap/test/ at all--and failing--when I only told it to look in sass/bootstrap/vendor?

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    compass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          sassDir: 'sass',
          cssDir: 'style'
        },
        files: {
          'style/bootstrap.css': 'sass/bootstrap/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: [
          'sass/bootstrap/vendor/assets/stylesheets'
        ],
        tasks: ['compass']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'compass',
    'watch'
  ]);
};
```

`$ grunt`:

```
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
directory style/bootstrap/templates/project/
directory style/bootstrap/test/dummy_sass_only/
directory style/bootstrap/test/dummy_node_mincer/
directory style/bootstrap/vendor/assets/stylesheets/
directory style/bootstrap/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/
directory style/bootstrap/test/dummy_rails/app/assets/stylesheets/
    error sass/bootstrap/templates/project/styles.sass (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-compass.
```

Answer (score 2):

`grunt-contrib-compass` works different than other grunt tasks as you don't specify individual files. Compass is a framework that has it's own conventions for resolving files. So the task `grunt-contrib-compass` just provides an interface to configure Compass through Grunt.

See the usage examples in grunt-contrib-compass's docs: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#example-config

Comment: If you want to compile sass files individually use `grunt-contrib-sass`. There isn't a work around for compass, its a framework.